# How to convert or how to implement touch behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have implemented **MouseDragElementBehavior** to my application before but unfortunately I use the application now using touch panel.

Before, obviously I drag using the mouse, but now because I am using touch panel, the MouseDragElementBehavior **won't work**.

Is there a way to convert this? My only changes to my application is by using Touch Panel and no changes to my application at all.

The rest like what a mouse can do is also doable by touching but dragging is not supported.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There currently isn't any official Drag for touch. You can however create your own thouch event for such by responding and combining touch events.

- PreviewTouchDown  *For starting your own start drag function on element so add the TouchMove event here to the object*
- TouchMove *For dragging the object visual*
- PreviewTouchUp *For stop dragging stop the TouchMove event here*
- TouchEnter *Check if the object you entered accept drops*

Or you can of course google for libraries that already implemented this kind of behavior.

I have googled it a bit and found [a good walktrought](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649090.aspx) for windows applications.
And with the [Touch Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can get all the touch points in the application (multiple fingers) and implement your own behavior.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,.. As you suggested I did research first and maybe combining some of those gathered examples but unluckily most of the touch implementation is on Windows phone or more on silverlight but not applicable to wpf.. I will still try to implement your suggestions.. thanks,,.

Comment: Added extra info. Does that help you?